# Google App Engine - NDB - INDEX Quesions

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I had the following question about GAE NDB - Index.

1. I assume you can specify index via `index.yaml` or within the model definition using property option, `indexed = true`. Am I correct? If yes is one preferred over the other?
2. Is there a way to add/drop index during the life cycle of the data objects?
3. Can I specify an index on a structured property field? 
      If so, then can you please let me know** as the syntax for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the properties that can be indexed (i.e. those that aren't variants of Blob) are indexed, which means you can filter or sort by them on their own. Adding single-property indexes to index.yaml would be unusual. Setting indexed=False for a property will mean fewer write-operations when saving entities, but will mean filtering or sorting by the property is no longer possible. I'd suggest reading the [documentation on indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes).

If you want to filter or sort (in combination) by more than one property, then you need to include them in index.yaml. However, as you run code in the development server, if it requires an index that hasn't yet been specified, then index.yaml will be modified to contain a suitable index for the query being run. Adding indexes manually isn't necessarily something you'll ever have to do.

You can't index an entire StructuredProperty, the properties of Structured Properties are individually indexed, and don't need to think about them any differently than for regular properties. If you want to manually specify a multi-property index that includes a sub-property, then you should be able to do so by using 'property.subproperty' (e.g. 'address.city').

Comment: I disagree with your statement that single-property indexes are unusual in index.yaml. In my project, I do a projection query on one property, which requires a single-property index. To create an index in GCP datastore, you need to have its definition in index.yaml and then run '$ gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml'.

Answer (score 1):

s1) Yes, you can set certain properties as being indexed. Some property types do not allow indexing at all. It's preferable to set the indexes programmatically within each model definition.

2) Although you can drop the index programmatically (i.e. remove indexed=True), I would not recommend it. It will leave your data store in inconsistent state.

3) It's not possible to set index on a structured property, however, you can set a Key relationship between your model and the models in the structured property.

See:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties

> "You can specify the usual property options for structured properties
>   (except indexed)."

Comment: Thanks. I got confused where in the document it said that structured property cannon be indexed. I realized that it meant the whole structured property and not the individual element.

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered the hard way (see [GAE python NDB projection query working in development but not in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623464/gae-python-ndb-projection-query-working-in-development-but-not-in-production)), there's a big difference between having an index (and therefore needing an entry in index.yaml) and marking properties as indexed or not indexed. These things are there for different purposes:

- Having an index allows you to search, sort, or do projection queries.
- Marking properties as indexed or not tells an index which entities to include in the index and which to ignore.

Yea, absolutely, you can add or drop index at any time:

1. Update your index.yaml
2. Then run one of the gcloud commands such as '$ gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml' or '$ gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml'

No, you can't create an index on a structured property. See more info here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#structured