# GAE python NDB projection query working in development but not in production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, projection, app-engine-ndb

I've been hitting my head against the wall because my Google App Engine python project has a very simple NDB projection query which works fine on my local machine, but mysteriously fails when deployed to production.

Adding to the mystery... as a test I added an identical projection on another property, and it works in both dev and production! Could anyone help please?! Here are more details:

I have the following entity that represents an expense:

```py
class Entry(ndb.Model):
    datetime = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True, required=True)
    amount = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False, required=True)
    payee = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True) 
    comment = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    # ...
```

Later on in the code I am doing a projection on Entry.payee (to get a list of all payees). As a test I also added a projection on Entry.datetime:

```py
log_msg = '' # For passing debug info to the browser

payeeObjects = Entry.query(ancestor=exp_traq_key(exp_traq_name), projection=[Entry.payee]).fetch()
payees = []
for obj in payeeObjects:
    payees.append(obj.payee)
log_msg += '%d payees: %s' % (len(payees), str(payees))

log_msg += ' ------------------- ' # a visual separator

dtObjects = Entry.query(ancestor=exp_traq_key(exp_traq_name), projection=[Entry.datetime]).fetch()
dts = []
for obj in dtObjects:
    dts.append(obj.datetime)
log_msg += '%d datetimes: %s' % (len(dts), str(dts))

#...other code, including passing log_msg down to the client
```

Here's the output in dev environment (notice a list of payees and a list of datetimes are displayed in console):

[image]

And here's the output when deployed to app engine. I can't get it to return a list of payees. It keeps returning an empty list even though in dev it returns the list fine:

[image]

I've ensured that I have the indexes properly set up on GAE:

[image]

Please help!

---

**2018-12-05 Update**:
I added a couple more entries in production and they got picked up! See screenshot. But the older entries are still not being returned.
[image]

My immediate reaction is that the datastore index needs to be "refreshed" somehow so it can "see" old entries. BUT the thing is I removed and recreated the index yesterday, which means it should have old entries... So still need help resolving this mystery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Darn it wasn't intuitive at all. I wish GAE documentation was better on this point...

My datastore in production contains a lot of previously created entries. As part of my latest code where I'm trying to do the projection on Entry.payee, I had to change the definition of Entry.payee from unindexed to indexed, like so:

```
payee = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True, required=True) # Originally was indexed=False
```

So now all those entries sitting in the datastore are being ignored by the projection query because the index on payee ignores those entries.

So what I need to do now is somehow migrate all those old entities to be **indexed=True**.

---

**Update** - here's how I did this migration. Turned out simpler than expected.

```
def runPayeeTypeMigration(exp_traq_name):
  Entry.query(ancestor=exp_traq_key(exp_traq_name)).fetch()
  for entry in entries:
    entry.put()
```

This works by reading all entries into the updated datastructure (the one where Entry.payee is indexed=True) and writes it back to the datastore, so that the entity will now be indexed.